# JQueryMobile Listview Header Text Abbreviation

Tags: listview, text, header, jquery-mobile, abbreviation

How to change the abbreviation setting of a listview header entry?

Lets say my window is big enough, the list entry is fully written like it should be. If the window is smaller, the text is abbreviated with '...' -> how could I influence the way when and how this is done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the Jquery mobile css:

EDIT: I'm sorry, I think you need this one if you want to change the `overflow` property of a list:
`.ui-li, .ui-li.ui-field-contain { display: block; margin:0; position: relative; overflow: visible; text-align: left; border-width: 0; border-top-width: 1px; }
.ui-li .ui-btn-text a.ui-link-inherit { text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;  }`

The text-overflow and overflow properties are the ones you need.
(`text-overflow: ellipsis` doesn't work in firefox and old IE though)

Comment: to be honest, im not getting your point, deactivating the ellipsis effect does not change this '...'-abbrevation in my case..

Comment: I thought you just wanted to change when your text is abbreviated or not. Do you want to change the '..' into something else? .....or am I missing the point here....

Comment: I think it is my fault. I'll try to explain: The '...'-abbreviation is made through the overflow: elipsis right? If I remove the overflow attribute, it is still abreviating with '..'. That is why I thought it is not the right attribute. And for now, it is working in Firefox =)

Comment: and what I want to achieve: for example 'only start abbreviating when window smaller 800px' or 'never abbreviate' or 'abbreviate only complete words' .. something like this :) Iam trying to find out how to manage the word-abbreviation =)

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? can't get it to work here (the `text-overflow: ellipsis` property). I really wouldn't know how to solve your problem.